# What is the difference between "uniform" distribution and "even" distribution?

Tags: terminology

I was reading a question in mechanics where it was written that mass of the rod is evenly distributed, but it was supposed to be "uniformly distributed". What is the difference between "uniform" distribution and "even" distribution?

Comment: In mechanics, I would say these are synonyms of each other, i.e. there is no difference in meaning in this context. The line density is constant at every point on the rod.

Answer (score 1):

"Uniformly distributed" is a concept from statistics (at least that's where I heard it first). If a probability is uniform, it means that the probability function is the same for all possible outcomes. If the mass of a rod is uniformly distributed, it should similarly be taken to mean that every single transversal slice of a given thickness has the same mass.

"Evenly distributed" is AFAIK not that well-defined. It should probably be taken to mean that the distribution is reasonably close to uniform, but not necessarily quite uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform distribution is such taht the density is constant

$$\rho(\vec{r})=Const.$$

On the other hand, an even distribution just means symmetric. The asme for even functions:

$$f(-x)=f(x)$$
The former is a particular case of the latter. In both cases, the center of mass will be in the middle.

Comment: I don't think your definition of "even" is the same as the OP. It seems to me that the OP is asking about the difference between being uniformly-distributed and being evenly-distributed.